# XPath expression where attribute with a suffix matches another element's attribute w/o the suffixes?

Tags: xpath

I am looking for an XPath expression that selects the `him`s that have parent, `gramps`'s with `name`'s that have the same root name with the `hims` having a `Jr` suffix and there is a `store` `name` that looks like it is named after a `gramps`.  In the example below that would only be `Bill`.

```
<root>

<gramps name="Bill">
   <him name="Bill Jr">
      <kid name="Bill III"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>
<gramps name="Tom">
   <him name="Al">
      <kid name="Al Jr"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>
<gramps name="Bob">
   <him name="Bob Jr">
      <kid name="Sam"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>

<store name="Bill's" />
<store name="Tom's" />
<store name="Pete's" />

</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will select what you need...

```
/*/gramps[../store/@name=concat(@name,"'s")]/him[@name=concat(../@name,' Jr')]
```

This will select `Bill Jr` because you said you wanted to select the `him`.

If you want to select the `gramps` (`Bill`), just put `him` in a predicate...

```
/*/gramps[../store/@name=concat(@name,"'s")][him[@name=concat(../@name,' Jr')]]
```